# Disable or remap emergency escape in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to disable the [emergency escape](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Emergency-Escape.html) feature in console emacs, or remap it to another key combination? I have a bad habit of hitting `C-g` multiple times while navigating, and it's frustrating to get dumped out to a shell sometimes when I'm on a slow connection.

Comment: This problem drives me crazy, multiple times one day.

Answer (score 3):

You can always cancel the emergency escape by [answering `n` to both prompts](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emergency-Escape.html#Emergency-Escape).

You can call [`set-input-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Modes.html) or `set-quit-char` to change the quit character. You could leave `C-g` bound to `keyboard-quit` to only divert the emergency quit functionality.

I don't think you can turn off the emergency quit character, just reassign it. And since it has to be a single character, that doesn't leave many alternate places to put it.